# MySQL Inner Join Query To Get Records Not Present in Other Table

Tags: mysql

I have table 1, all_countries, as follows-

```
id   |  country
------------------
1    |  USA
2    |  China
3    |  India
4    |  France
5    |  UK
6    |  Australia
```

and I also have table 2, supported_countries, as -

```
id   |  country
------------------
1    |  USA
2    |  China
```

Now I need a query that would give me result that includes all countries that ARE NOT supported

So as per above example I should get

```
India
France
UK
Australia
```

I am using the following query -

> SELECT ac.country FROM all_countries ac INNER JOIN supported_countries sc ON sc.country_name != ac.country_name

It works fine, except when supported_countries table is empty, it doesn't show any records. How to achieve this result?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` will do that elegantly;

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM all_countries a
LEFT JOIN supported_countries s
  ON a.country = s.country
WHERE s.id IS NULL;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1df7f/1).

Answer (score 5):

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM all_countries 
  WHERE country NOT IN (SELECT country FROM supported_countries)
```

Comment: Subqueries are often [less performant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856164/sql-joins-vs-sql-subqueries-performance) than explicit joins. They are easier to read, but do not scale well.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ac.country FROM all_countries ac 
LEFT JOIN supported_countries sc ON 
sc.country_name = ac.country_name
WHERE ISNULL(sc.country_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Joachim Isaksson gave me the clue, I tested this very similar query and worked on my database by replacing variables.

```
SELECT * FROM all_countries 
LEFT JOIN supported_countries ON all_countries.id = supported_countries.id 
WHERE supported_countries.id IS NULL
```

I gave the question and that Joachim's answer my thumbs up. Cheers !