# Finding duplicates between 2 large tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, `TABLEA` and `TABLEB`.

These contain pretty much the same data, around 90,000 records (30 fields)

There is a field, `caller_id` that is in both tables.

What I'm trying to do, is to find records in `TABLEB` that are in `TABLEA`.

I currently have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEB
WHERE caller_id IN (SELECT caller_id FROM TABLEA)
```

This query is incredibly slow (takes over 2 minutes), which isn't ideal

Is there a way I can possibly speed this up?

Thanks

UPDATE

```
1   SIMPLE  b   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11719   NULL
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11719   NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tables are not that big.  Try this approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEB b
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM TABLEA a where a.caller_id = b.caller_id);
```

And, be sure there is an index on `TABLEA(caller_id)`:

```
create index tablea_caller_id on tablea(caller_id);
```

Some versions of MySQL do a poor job optimizing `in` with a subquery.  The `exists` clause gets around this.

Comment: Adding the index seems to have speeded up the query!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subquery use join check for an index on `caller_id`

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.* FROM TABLEB b
INNER JOIN TABLEA a
 ON (a.caller_id =b.caller_id)
```

Also read [SQL Joins Vs SQL Subqueries (Performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856164/sql-joins-vs-sql-subqueries-performance)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that! Although, it is equally as slow in terms of finding records

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid . . . This could return duplicate values in the result set, if `caller_id` is not unique in `tableA`.