# How to speed up this MySQL Query or change it so that it's faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

Example SQLFiddle here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba20f/2

The example only has 5 rows in each of the 2 tables, but still takes too long to load IMO.  Wish it would let me insert more, which will increase time dramatically with more rows and data...

This query is taking too long to complete.  The rows in `wp_quantum_purchases` and `wp_quantum_sales` are around 11,000 each.  `wp_hunter_quote_parts` and `wp_hunter_quotes` tables are completely empty (as this is to store data moving forward in the system).

So, I have imported data from another system (purchases and sales) into separate tables.  What I need to do is to be able to show only the `IsActive = 1` parts for both purchases and sales tables, however, if `wp_hunter_quote_parts` table has these parts (`ItemName`) than it should pull the data from the `wp_hunter_quote_parts` and `wp_hunter_quotes` tables instead.  What I have here is 3 FULL OUTER JOINS, but I feel that this can be done so that it doesn't take over 90 seconds to load the data.  Especially, since I'm using a LIMIT on it of 40 at a time.

```
(SELECT IFNULL(qp.ItemName, qs.ItemName) AS name, IFNULL(qp.TimeAdded, qs.TimeAdded) AS created, qs.SalesDate AS effective, qp.VendorName AS supplier, qp.Source AS source, qp.VendorType AS type, qp.Price AS cost, qs.Price AS price, CAST((((CAST(qs.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - CAST(qp.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2))) / CAST(qp.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2))) * 100) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS markup, qs.CustomerName AS customer, qs.CustomerListID AS customerListID, qp.VendorListID AS vendorListID, '' AS itemListID
                FROM wp_quantum_purchases AS qp
                LEFT JOIN wp_quantum_sales AS qs ON (qs.ItemName = qp.ItemName AND qs.IsActive = 1)
                WHERE qp.IsActive = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
                    WHERE qp.ItemName = hqp.ItemName AND hqp.IsActive = 1
                )
            )
            UNION ALL
(SELECT IFNULL(qp.ItemName, qs.ItemName) AS name, IFNULL(qp.TimeAdded, qs.TimeAdded) AS created, qs.SalesDate AS effective, qp.VendorName AS supplier, qp.Source AS source, qp.VendorType AS type, qp.Price AS cost, qs.Price AS price, CAST((((CAST(qs.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - CAST(qp.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2))) / CAST(qp.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2))) * 100) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS markup, qs.CustomerName AS customer, qs.CustomerListID AS customerListID, qp.VendorListID AS vendorListID, '' AS itemListID
                FROM wp_quantum_sales AS qs
                LEFT JOIN wp_quantum_purchases AS qp ON (qp.ItemName = qs.ItemName AND qp.IsActive = 1)
                WHERE qs.IsActive = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
                    WHERE qs.ItemName = hqp.ItemName AND hqp.IsActive = 1
                )
            )
            UNION ALL 
(SELECT hqp.ItemName AS name, hq.Quote_Date AS created, hqp.SalesDate AS effective, hqp.VendorName AS supplier, hqp.Source AS source, hqp.VendorType AS type, hqp.Cost AS cost, hqp.Price AS price, CAST((((CAST(hqp.Price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) - CAST(hqp.Cost AS DECIMAL(10,2))) / CAST(hqp.Cost AS DECIMAL(10,2))) * 100) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS markup, IFNULL(hq.Customer_FullName, 'N/A') AS customer, hq.Customer_ListID AS customerListID, hqp.VendorListID AS vendorListID, hqp.Item_ListID AS itemListID
                FROM wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
                LEFT JOIN wp_hunter_quotes AS hq ON (hq.id = hqp.QuoteID)
                WHERE hqp.IsActive = 1)

ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT 0, 40;
```

Can anyone help me here?  I need to merge both the purchases and sales tables into a combined table (which this is doing... undoubtably very slow though), and than needs to outer join against the `hunter_quote_parts` table so that if `hqp.IsActive = 1` exists, than we need to pull in that data from the `wp_hunter_quote_parts` table instead of that from the combined other 2 tables.

How can I make this query work faster or change it so that it functions the same, but faster?  Please anyone help?

What would be a great solution, if possible, would be to use something like this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_quantum_purchases AS qp, wp_quantum_sales AS qs
LEFT JOIN wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp ON ((hqp.ItemName = qp.ItemName || hqp.ItemName = qs.ItemName) AND hqp.IsActive = 1)
LEFT JOIN wp_hunter_quotes AS hq ON (hq.id = hqp.QuoteID)
WHERE qp.IsActive = 1 || qs.IsActive = 1;
```

However, the problem with this query is that it relies on `wp_quantum_purchases` or `wp_quantum_sales` to have a row in it that has IsActive = 1 before it will allow it to grab any data from `wp_hunter_quote_parts` or `wp_hunter_quotes` tables.  This is an unacceptable query, as it needs to capture data moving forward in my system, and data moving forward will be captured inside of the `wp_hunter_quotes` and `wp_hunter_quote_parts` tables.  The `ItemName` could be a new item that doesn't even exist in the quantum tables.  Although if it doesn't exist in the quote tables, I need to show the previous data from `wp_quantum_purchases` and `wp_quantum_sales` if it exists.  How is anyone supposed to this??  This seems very basic and should be possible to do, but why is it so difficult to understand?  And than on top of it, the query that I found to work for this is taking way too long to complete.  Not sure what more you need here...?

Comment: Sub Queries make the query execution slower. So try not to use sub-queries

Comment: Sub Queries?  You mean `LEFT` joins?

Comment: I am building a `markup` column with data from both sales and purchase tables, so I'm not sure if I can do that without `LEFT` joining on the other table here.  I suppose I could calculate the markup outside of the mysql query, but would rather do it in the query (if possible).

Comment: Sub Queries means query within query. JOINS are different than sub-queries. In your case, following is the subquery (Starting with SELECT).



AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
                    WHERE qs.ItemName = hqp.ItemName AND hqp.IsActive = 1
                )

Comment: The sub queries that you speak of is not the problem, it still take a very long time to complete if I remove the sub queries here...  so, there is very little to no difference in time.

Comment: Sure you might want to have a look at this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856164/sql-joins-vs-sql-subqueries-performance

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that is not the problem here.  There is a much more significant problem that is being overlooked with this query.  Subqueries here are not drastically increasing the query time, since if I remove the sub queries, they do not have a significant effect on the time it takes to complete the query.

Comment: Yes you are right, it depends on the query sometimes its not the sub-query that makes the execution slow.. There are other factors too.'

Comment: You mention using `FULL JOIN` but instead I see `UNION`, so maybe try FULL JOIN instead. Those are two different operations. FULL JOIN is like LEFT and RIGHT JOIN combined and allows you to use IFNULL() in the same way.

Comment: `FULL JOIN` is `UNION` and `UNION ALL` in MySQL, as far as I know.  You can't simply do `FULL JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Ok, sure thing, I've added an SQL Fiddle, with only 5 rows in each table `quantum_purchases` and `quantum_sales` while leaving both quote tables blank.

Comment: Your SQLFiddle doesn't have any indexes - is that the same on the "real" database? If so, you can get major improvements by adding indexes...

Comment: I have indexes in the real database, I just couldn't add them into the fiddle, since the fiddle kept saying `> 8000` and produced character error, so I removed them.

Comment: Thanks @NevilleK, I added indexes on `IsActive` as well as `ItemName` on all 3 tables and query has major improvements!  This was the major problem.  Thanks for pointing that out!