# SQL reporting query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE Party
    (
      PartyID INT IDENTITY
                  PRIMARY KEY ,
      StatusID INT ,
      Weigth INT ,
      OldWeigth INT
    );
GO
CREATE TABLE PartyLocation
    (
      PartyLocationID INT IDENTITY
                          PRIMARY KEY ,
      PartyID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Party ( PartyID ) ,
      LocationID INT ,
      Distance INT
    );
GO
CREATE TABLE PartyRole
    (
      PartyRoleID INT IDENTITY
                      PRIMARY KEY ,
      PartyID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Party ( PartyID ) ,
      RoleID INT
    );
```

with some simple data.

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.Party
        ( StatusID, Weigth, OldWeigth )
VALUES  ( 1, -- StatusID - int
          10, -- Age - int
          20 -- OldAge - int
          ),
        ( 1, 15, 25 ),
        ( 2, 20, 30 );

INSERT  INTO dbo.PartyLocation
        ( PartyID, LocationID, Distance )
VALUES  ( 1, -- PartyID - int
          1, -- LocationID - int
          100  -- Distance - int
          ),
        ( 1, 2, 200 ),
        ( 1, 3, 300 ),
        ( 2, 1, 1000 ),
        ( 2, 2, 2000 ),
        ( 3, 1, 10000 );

INSERT  INTO dbo.PartyRole
        ( PartyID, RoleID )
VALUES  ( 1, -- PartyID - int
          1  -- RoleID - int
          ),
        ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 2, 2 ),
        ( 3, 1 );
```

I want to query the following information

1. Return sum of Weigth of all parties that has roleID = 1 in PartyRole table
2. Return sum of OldWeigth of all parties that has statusID = 2
3. Return sum of distances of all parties that has locationID = 3
4. Return sum of distances of all parties that has roleID = 2

So the expected results are

```
FilteredWeigth FilteredOldWeigth FilteredDistance AnotherFilteredDistance
-------------- ----------------- ---------------- -----------------------
45             30                600              3600
```

Can we write a query that will query each table just once? If no what will be the most optimal way to query the data?

Comment: Well done on the [mcve], have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: In `Party` table, you are not inserting anything into `PartyID` but only to `StatusID`, nonetheless a nicely explained question

Comment: the column is an identity column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
    FilteredWeigth = SUM(CASE WHEN  RoleID = 1 AND RN_P = 1 THEN Weigth END) ,
    FilteredOldWeigth = SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 2 AND RN_P = 1 THEN OldWeigth END), 
    FilteredDistance = SUM(CASE WHEN  LocationID = 3 AND RN_L = 1 THEN Distance END), 
    AnotherFilteredDistance = SUM(CASE WHEN RoleID = 2 THEN Distance END) 
 FROM (
        SELECT  P.Weigth, P.StatusID, P.OldWeigth, PL.LocationID, PL.Distance, PR.RoleID, 
                RN_P = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.PartyID ORDER BY PL.PartyLocationID),
                RN_L = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PL.LocationID ORDER BY PR.PartyRoleID)
        FROM Party P
        INNER JOIN PartyLocation PL ON P.PartyID = PL.PartyID
        INNER JOIN PartyRole PR ON P.PartyID = PR.PartyID
   ) AS T
```

Comment: why you put CASE WHEN LocationID = 1 AND RoleID = 1 in the FilteredWeigth, I only want to filter based on RoleID.

Comment: Because of PartyLocation  join, every role row multiply with PartyLocation  row. For getting single Party row i added LocationID = 1 filter.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what if there are no corresponding row in partylocation with LocationID = 1? I mean I need to generate this query from the application side, how can I get that '1' value ?

Comment: You have not updated  FilteredOldWeigth = SUM(CASE WHEN LocationID = 1 AND StatusID = 2 THEN OldWeigth END) this part

Comment: I added row_number to this fields too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158603/discussion-between-artashes-khachatryan-and-sarslan).

Answer (score 0):

the below gives

45  20  300 3600

the third column gives 300 which does not correspond to your expected result.

```
with q1
as
(
   select sum(weigth) FilteredWeigth
   from party join partyrole on party.partyid = partyrole.partyid
   where partyrole.RoleID = '1'
),
q2 as
(
   select sum(weigth) OldWeigth from party where StatusID = '2'
),
q3 as (
   select sum(Distance) FilteredDistance
   from party join PartyLocation on party.partyid = PartyLocation.partyid
   where PartyLocation.locationID = '3'
),
q4 as 
(
    select sum(Distance) AnotherFilteredDistance
    from party join partyrole on party.partyid = partyrole.partyid
               join PartyLocation on party.partyid = PartyLocation.partyid
    where partyrole.RoleID = '2'
)
select FilteredWeigth,OldWeigth,FilteredDistance,AnotherFilteredDistance 
from q1,q2,q3,q4
```

Comment: You have accessed the party table 4 times.... I think there must be more optimal way to get the results.

Comment: very true, but if the data is not alot as above. if this was 1 million rows this is not optimal. I was assuming his data size was bugger all @sarslan answer is alot better, but harder to read..its a trade off

Answer (score 0):

When Using Individual Queries, you can achieve this using the following

**Return sum of Weight of all parties that has roleID = 1 in PartyRole table**

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Weight) FilteredWeigth 
  FROM dbo.Party P
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
      SELECT
      1
    FROM dbo.PartyRole PR 
      WHERE PR. PartyID = P.PartyID
    AND PR.RoleId = 1
  )
```

**Return sum of OldWeigth of all parties that has statusID = 2**

```
SELECT 
  SUM(OldWeigth) FilteredOldWeigth 
  FROM dbo.Party P
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
      SELECT
      1
    FROM dbo.PartyRole PR 
      WHERE PR. PartyID = P.PartyID
    AND PR.RoleId = 2
  )
```

**Return sum of distances of all parties that has locationID = 3**

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Distance) FilteredDistance 
  FROM dbo.PartyLocation
    WHERE LocationID = 3
```

**Return sum of distances of all parties that has roleID = 2**

```
SELECT SUM(Distance) FROM PartyLocation PL
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
      SELECT 1 FROM PartyRole PR
      WHERE PR.PartyID = PL.PartyID
        AND PR.Roleid = 2
   )
```

If you want to get the result of all these in a single result set. then maybe you can try a pivot query. Like this

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 
      'FilteredWeigth' ColNm,
      SUM(Weigth) Val 
      FROM dbo.Party P
      WHERE EXISTS
      (
          SELECT
          1
        FROM dbo.PartyRole PR 
          WHERE PR. PartyID = P.PartyID
        AND PR.RoleId = 1
      )
UNION
  SELECT 
        'FilteredOldWeigth' ColNm,
  SUM(OldWeigth) Val 
      FROM dbo.Party P
      WHERE EXISTS
      (
          SELECT
          1
        FROM dbo.PartyRole PR 
          WHERE PR. PartyID = P.PartyID
        AND PR.RoleId = 2
      )
  UNION
  SELECT 
  'FilteredDistance'    ColNm,
  SUM(Distance) Val 
      FROM dbo.PartyLocation
        WHERE LocationID = 3
  UNION
  SELECT
  'AnotherFilteredDistance' ColNm,
  SUM(Distance) Val FROM PartyLocation PL
      WHERE EXISTS
      (
          SELECT 1 FROM PartyRole PR
          WHERE PR.PartyID = PL.PartyID
            AND PR.Roleid = 2
       )
)
SELECT
  *
  FROM CTE
  PIVOT
  (
      SUM(Val)
      FOR ColNm IN
      (
        [FilteredWeigth],[FilteredOldWeigth],[FilteredDistance],[AnotherFilteredDistance]
       )
  )Pvt
```

The Result Will be

[image: Sample Result]

Comment: why not just join them together?

Comment: What if a record in the Party does not have an entry in Party role or Party Location? Then we need Left or Right Join. So I thought this will suite more

Comment: all your queries above in the CTE are aggregation functions doing a sum thus returning a garunteed one row whether data exists or not. joining 4 queries of 1 row earch = 1 row. Unioning just to pivot is pointless and unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I could think of only three possible options:

1. Union query with four different select statements as answered by @ab-bennett
2. Join all tables then use select statements as answered by sarslan
3. Mix of `1` and `2`, based on experiments

Coming to the question you asked:

> Can we write a query that will query each table just once?

Assuming best performance is the goal, following could happen in each of the above cases:

1. All `select` statements would have their own `where` clause. This would perform best when `where` produces `few rows` compared to the `count(*)`. Note that Joins are terrible for very large tables.
2. A join is made once, and the desired output is obtained from the same Joined table. This would perform optimal when `where` produces significant number of rows and the table is not too big to join.
3. You can mix JOIN / IN / EXISTS / WHERE to [optimize your queries based on number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11252161/3991696) you are having in table. This approach could be used when your dataset cardinality might not vary a lot.

Comment: I have to generate this queries from the application. So I cant calculate the number of rows to make a decision based on that.

Comment: Usually, one could go about estimating the `number of rows` in tables based on `number of users` of the application

Comment: No, that is not my case.